# sql query and quotes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not sure where to put the quotes, at least I think thats the problem. It tells me "syntax error in query, Incomplete query clause.".   I'm use ms access.

```
select 
    'MAIN DATABASE'.CoupaREQ, 
    'MAIN DATABASE'.OldServiceTag, 
    'REQ Lookup'.'Old Tag Serial', 'REQ Lookup'.'Coupa Req', 
    'REQ lookup'.'Req From Tracker'
from 
    'MAIN DATABASE', 'REQ Lookup'
where 
    'MAIN DATABASE'.ID = 'REQ Lookup'.id ;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Use square brackets when needed and not single quotes.

Comment: I used the code above but access still gives me the same error? Is that because I'm not using Join command?

Comment: Forpas was right, i guess being access, it needs brackets and not quotes.